# Avoid Overload when functions differ only in the number of parameters

Tags: vb.net, overloading

I have Functions like:

```
Public Overloads Function(byval Par1 as Integer) as Array
dim arr_i(0) as double
arr_i(0) = Par1
Return arr_i
end function

Public Overloads Function(byval Par1 as Integer, byval Par2 as Integer) as Array
dim arr_i(1) as double
arr_i(0) = Par1
arr_i(1) = Par2
Return arr_i
End function

Public Overloads Function(byval Par1 as Integer, byval Par2 as Integer, byval Par3 as Integer) as Array
dim arr_i(2) as double
arr_i(0) = Par1
arr_i(1) = Par2
arr_i(2) = Par3
Return arr_i
End function
```

My Functions are a bit more complex but this is the backbone. The return and parameter types do not change just the number of parameters. I try to avoid optional parameters due to incompatibility problems.

Looking at my overloads functions (say we use a loop to calculate something with the parameters) there is the same code in every function just the number of parameters change. Say I want this for 1 to 20 parameters I would have to write (or copy) the same code over and over again. I have the feeling that this cannot be the best way of solving this problem but cannot come up with a more efficient one. Is there a better way implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [paramarray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ct363x9h.aspx) in your case, It is actually a kind of passing parameter into a function/procedure. You can modify your code as below to achieve your need.

```
'Function definition
Public Function test(ByVal ParamArray Pars() As Integer) As Integer()
    Return Pars
End Function

'Function calls
Call test(1, 2, 4, 5, 34, 34, 223, 42)
Call test(1, 2)
```